# How to go next activity

Tags: android

How to click next activity?

```
public void cancel(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
}
```

I can't get next activity.

Comment: what is your problem? Explain more on it...

Comment: call startActivity(intent);

Comment: Please refer http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void cancel(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startyActivity(intent);
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Because you must startActivity too.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```